# How do I select record based on first char of a value? - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a form that POSTS a postal code value (A1A1A1).  In my model I have a col of alpha chars that relate to the province that has postal codes that begin with that letter;

```
letter  |  province
-------------------
A       |  NLFD
B       |  NS
C       |  PEI
...
```

I am trying to get the record where the first char of my request (A1A1A1 - so 'A' in that case) equals the 'letter' value.

Is there a way to use LIKE and be specific about which char in the value?  Or do I need something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be that you get the first character of the postal code from the request and get the corresponding record from your database.

```
$pcode = $request->get('postalcode');  
$firstChar = substr($pcode,0,1);
and then  
Model::whereLetter($firstChar)->firstOrFail();
```

If you use this at multiple places then you may also consider declaring a global query scope in your model itself.

Comment: Thanks!  Worked as I hoped.